# long int "a" array has a previous declaration as double "a" array (dynamic memory allocation topic from microlearning c++ android app)

Tags: c++, arrays

I've deleted previous dynamic double "a" array and created a new same-named long int array. But code::blocks gives me an error: "a has a previous declaration as double a". Here is the program:

```
/*Write a C++ program that receives integer n and 
creates a dynamic array        a of n size
of doubles, then shows a 
maximum number in array, then array a is   
deleted,    then again receives
integer n and creates a dynamic array 
a of n size of long int, then shows      minimum number
in array.*/

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double temp;
    int *n = new int;
    cin >> *n;

    double *a = new double[*n];
    for (int i=0;i<*n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];


    for (int i = 0; i<*n; i++){
        if (temp<a[i]){
            temp=a[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Max. num in array: " << temp << endl;


    delete[] a;



    cin >> *n;

    long int *a = new long int[*n];

    for (int i=0;i<*n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];

    for (int i = 0; i<*n; i++){
        if (temp>a[i]){
            temp = a[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "Min. num in array: " << temp << endl;

    delete n;
    delete []a;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot re-define a variable that was previously defined in the same scope. Initially you have

```
double *a; // a is a pointer to double
```

then you try

```
long int *a; // a is a pointer to long int
```

It doesn't matter that you `delete[] a;`. The variable `a` continues to exist, it is of a pointer type. Of course its allocated memory is deleted, but still you cannot re-declare it.

The instructor probably meant

```
char* a;
a = new char[n*sizeof(double)];
//...
delete[] a;
a = new char[n*sizeof(long int)];
```

If you don't want a conflict and want to keep the pointer of type `double*` and `long int*` respectively, you can put the variable inside a scope, like

```
{
    double *a = new double[n];
    // ...
    delete[] a;
} // end of scope, `a` ceases to exist

{ // new scope
    long int *a = new long int[n];
    // ...
    delete[] a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but why creator of e-learning app wants we to do so? (His asking is in multiline comment on the top)
   Probably he were confused something...
       Thank you veeery much.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem asks. It probably asks for allocating raw memory, once for `n` doubles, then for `n` long ints. You cannot change the type of the pointer once created.

Comment: I've simply renamed a new long int array into "a2".

Comment: @perpetuum Yes that's perfectly fine, as I said the statement of the problem is not crystal clear.

Comment: Thanx again. As a some sort of cpp beginner, my ultimate goal was to reach a topic of dynamic a.m. from the reason of wish from ones of my superiors in the institute where I'm working to make a "fishing judge" programm. Aim is a flexible input for number of equipes, who gets the biggest fish, whose not, weight of catch per equip, min and max of catches per equip, total catch...etc...
    The only thing that eventually "drow-backed" me were fact that I've somehow felt that it is in conection with dynamic memory... a topic first seen in my life yesterday... but persistance and perseverance must.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redeclare it. As you have freed up the memory space. But consider this,  you can again allocate memory to the double array
Check here [Here](http://ideone.com/CSpEV3)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *a;
    a = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i * 2;
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
    delete [] a;
    a = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i * 3;
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
    delete [] a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no, you can allocate a new array and make `a` point to it  . A deleted array canot be "resurrected".

Comment: You want to say that we are by "delete[] a" - we are deleting a memory allocated for an array, not the array itself. So, I understand, definetly we couldn't "resurrect" deleted array inside the same scope but we can "ressurect" it outside of the scope...

Comment: yeah. Thats what i am saying. Hope you got it

Comment: @KishanKumar Just to make sure, you **cannot** allocate memory to an array of doubles using a different pointer type, the pointer has to be of type `double`. What you can do though is to allocate raw memory to `n*sizeof(double)` bytes.

Comment: @vsoftco I know that thing.

Comment: @KishanKumar that code makes a new array, it does not reallocate the old one. `new` makes a new array.

Comment: @perpetuum `delete[] a` deletes the array and the memory allocated.  I think you and Kishan are both confusing `a` with the array

Comment: Extremly thanx... I often lose the sight that pointers "always points". And of course we can (some of us) easely confuse that with arrays itself becouse visualy and this pointer has angled brackets, too...

Answer (score 1):

variable "a" is declared as double at first in main function, and you can't use "a" for another variable's name in same scope.